# Type checking algorithm for tuple in let expression

Tags: haskell, typechecking, hindley-milner

This block gives

```
f = let (x1, x2, x3) = (\y1 -> (y1, y1), \y2 -> x1 (x1 y2), \y3 -> x2 (x2 y3))
    in x1
```

error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t1 ~ (t1, t1)
Relevant bindings include
  y2 :: t1 (bound at test.hs:1:43)
  x1 :: t1 -> (t1, t1) (bound at test.hs:1:10)
  x2 :: t1 -> (t1, t1) (bound at test.hs:1:14)
  x3 :: t1 -> (t1, t1) (bound at test.hs:1:18)
In the first argument of ‘x1’, namely ‘(x1 y2)’
In the expression: x1 (x1 y2)
```

I want to know the algorithm behind type checking in tuples in `let` expression. I know the Hindley-Milney type checking algorithm when there is one variable on the left side. I want to know if there is any special algorithm in case of tuples/lists etc.

Comment: no it's the same - you can see the tuple as an value of type `(a,b,c)` here and use the same algorithm - just observe that two tuples have the same type IFF they have the same number of components and if the corresponding types of the components are equal

Comment: So you mean that it doesn't fail while type-checking the right side? I mean when it finishes type-checking `\y1 -> (y1, y1)`, does it immediately refine `x1`'s type to `x1 :: t -> (t, t)` or does it use `x1 :: a` to typecheck `\y2 -> x1 (x1 y2)` ?

Comment: are you talking about the (implementation-)details of the used algorithm? (this I don't know) - but from a practical perspective it should be an equivalence relation so that in your example `x1`, `a` and `t -> (t->t)` all fall in the same class of types to be identified.

Comment: Yes, I needed the implementation details. Mainly, I want to know whether it fails on the right side only or it fails in unification on the left side.

Comment: Pattern matching in the left hand side is equivalent to writing a mutually recursive 'let', provided the pattern always succeeds of course. Or you could replace `(x1,x2,x3)` with `x` and write `fst x`, `snd x`, `trd 3`, this would be exactly equivalent from the type checkers perspective. I'm not sure what this question is really about - it is pretty clear that the type checker has decided to fail particularly on the application of `x1` to `(x1 y2)` because this yields an infinite type.